# Delphi: communication among Frames

Tags: delphi, frames

How to communicate among frames and within a frame?
For example: a Frame 1 and a Frame 2.

The frame 2 is in the frame 1. To insert the frame 2 into the frame 1 I add frames from ToolPalette ->

```
type
  TFrame1 = class(TFrame)
  Frame22: TFrame2;

  var MyFrame1:TFrame1; // Now I can access to everything within a frame and from other frames too
implementation
```

But I have an error trying to access to MyFrame1 and to do something like MyFrame1.Button1.Enable within the frame 1 or from other frames:
"Exception class EAccessViolation with a message 'Access violation at address 0084858C in module 'P1.exe'"

How to access to the frame 1 from the frame 2? MyFrame1->Error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please delete the global variable declaration:

```
var MyFrame1: TFrame1;
```

It usually makes no sense for frames.

You can typecast the child frame's `Owner` to `TFrame1`, for example:

```
implementation

uses
  FrameUnit1;

procedure TFrame2.Test;
begin
  if Owner is TFrame1 then
    ShowMessage(TFrame1(Owner).Name);
end;
```

Comment: @Embarcadero, please give me an option to NOT generate those pesky global vars. And while you're at it, please stop adding new forms to the project's auto-created form lists (those two items are related). Thankyou. And +1.

Comment: `Owner` can't be "undeclared identifier" within the frame, because it's introduced from `TComponent`. Are you sure you didn't misspell it?

Comment: @Cosmin Tools -> Options -> [Enviroment options + VCL Designer] -> Auto create forms & data modules

Comment: @TOndrej Isn't the `Owner` always "root form" and the `Parent` is the windowed container which contains the control? Ie when you drop frame1 on form1 and frame2 on frame1, the Owner of the frame2 will be form1 but Parent will be frame1.

Comment: @ain No, it's the immediate Owner. In this case, the parent frame TFrame1.

Comment: @ain, @TOndrej, if you drom Frame2 on Frame1 in Frame1's editor, the owner would be Frame1. If you drop it on an *instance* of Frame1 while editing a Form, the owner should be the Form. I'd prefer walking the Parent list, to cover both situations. Or create the frame from code.

Comment: @Cosmin No, the owner will be the instance of `TFrame1`, not the form.

Comment: @TOndrej, test results: if you drop Frame2 on Frame1 while editing a Form the owner is.. none. Delphi's IDE doesn't let you do that. The only way to get a Frame2 onto Frame1 at design time is to add in the editor of Frame1 or add it at runtime, from code.

Comment: @Cosmin Sorry, I misread your comment first. If you drop an instance of TFrame2 on an "instance of TFrame1 while editing a form" then I think you're effectively dropping it on the form. If, however, TFrame1 is designed to contain a TFrame2 (which is what I believe is the case here) then - when you drop an instance of TFrame1 on a form, the child (TFrame2) frame's Owner will be that instance of TFrame1, not the "root" form.

Comment: @ain, @TOndrej: The parent for Frame2 is Frame1, but the Form is probably the owner of both. So the OP should use the Parent, not he Owner.

Comment: @Rudy Sorry but it's not, please try it and see for yourself.

Comment: I can't try right now (I'm in my clinic), but it is certain that the Parent is a TFrame1, since the TFrame2 was placed on it. If you use parent, it doesn't matter if the owner is the other frame or the form.

Comment: @TOndrej: if Frame1 is designed to contain a TFrame2, then TFrame1 will also be the parent. If TFrame1 is not designed to contain a Tframe2, but it is dropped on it when editing a form, then what is the parent and what is the owner? Probably the form, in both cases.

Comment: In that case ,it is better to use the Parent (whatever it is) and iterate over its Controls property to find a TFrame2 (assuming there is only one).

Comment: I created two frames, turned them into templates and dropped both on a form. The Owner and Parent of each of them was the form. Now I dropped a TFrame2Template on TFrame1, and the owner and parent of the TFrame2 was TFrame1. So it doesn't really matter whether you use Parent or Owner.

Comment: @Rudy I agree, the important thing is to use what works for you. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

TOndrej mentioned using the Owner, but that is usually the form, not Frame1. The Parent of Frame2 should be Frame1, so:

```
uses
  Frame1Unit;

procedure TFrame2.Test;
var
  C: TControl;
begin
  if Parent is TFrame1 then
    ShowMessage(TFrame1(Parent).Name)
  else 
    for C in Parent.Controls do
      if C is TFrame1 then
        ShowMessage(TFrame1(C).Name);
end;
```

**Updated** added code to use Parent.Controls to find a TFrame1.

Comment: *At design time*, while editing a Form, you can't place a Frame2 on a Frame1 so that Frame1 is the parent of Frame2. Try it yourself in the IDE. Even if it looks like Frame2 is parented by Frame1, drag it around and you'll see it's actually parented by the form. If you drop Frame2 on Frame1 *in Frame1's editor* then it's guaranteed that Frame2's owner is Frame1. As TOndrej told you, try it and you'll see. The immediate Parent is much less likely to be of `TFrame1` type: the Parent might very well be a `TScrollBox` or a `TPanel` that's in turn parented by `TFrame1`.

Comment: Can't chekc this right now, as I'm in my clinic. Will check this evening. Now, if the TFrame2 is placed on the TFrame1 in code... Please don't downvote yet. <g>